# Master - Master setup on Postgresql 10 + Ubuntu 18.04 + Pgpool II

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-10, pgpool

Does anybody have experience in configuring Pgpool II with Postgresql 10 on Ubuntu 18.04?

I am trying to setup Master - Master setup on Postgresql 10 + Ubuntu. I am trying to use Pgpool II

I will have two or more mater DB servers running on different IPs and my objective is synced with each other.

I am looking for an open-source solution/s Your thoughts, suggestion and experiences are kindly welcome.
Cheers

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why is simple master-slave replication not sufficient? What problem are you having? As it is your question is too broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 1):

you can set up master - slave replication using pgpool, master-master is not supported. 
To set up active - active replication you will need to use tool like SymmetricDS.
Cheers!